# Fragment при листании вкладок не но восстанавливается

Tags: tabs, android-fragment, android, java

У меня три вкладки, я могу вернуться со второй кладки на первую, но когда я возвращаюсь с третьей на вторую, то уже не могу вернуться на первую и программа отваливается в логах пишет.

В первой вкладке два фрагмента

```
<fragment

    android:name="com.example.eldos.callreport.Fragment1"
    android:id="@+id/frag1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment1"/>

<fragment
    android:name="com.example.eldos.callreport.Fragment2"
    android:id="@+id/frag2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment2"/>
```

код где создаются вкладки

```
public class ScreenOne extends Fragment {

    private SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    public ScreenOne() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_first, container, false);
        Log.i("log", "onCreateView");

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new SamplePagerAdapter());


        // Give the SlidingTabLayout the ViewPager, this must be
        // done AFTER the ViewPager has had it's PagerAdapter set.
        mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);


    }

    // Adapter
    class SamplePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        /**
         * Return the number of pages to display
         */
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 4;
        }

        /**
         * Return true if the value returned from is the same object as the View
         * added to the ViewPager.
         */
        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
            return o == view;
        }

        /**
         * Return the title of the item at position. This is important as what
         * this method returns is what is displayed in the SlidingTabLayout.
         */
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Screen " + (position + 1);
        }

        /**
         * Instantiate the View which should be displayed at position. Here we
         * inflate a layout from the apps resources and then change the text
         * view to signify the position.
         */
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            // Inflate a new layout from our resources
            View view = null;
            if(position == 0){
                 view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main,container, false);
                container.addView(view);
//                TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
//                title.setText("It's first page");
            }
            // Add the newly created View to the ViewPager


            // Retrieve a TextView from the inflated View, and update it's text
            if(position == 1) {
                 view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pager_item, container, false);
                container.addView(view);
                TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
                title.setText("It's first page");
            }
            if(position == 2) {
                 view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pager_item, container, false);
                container.addView(view);
                TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
                title.setText("It's first page");
            }
            else {
                view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pager_item, container, false);
                container.addView(view);
                TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
                title.setText("It's first page");
            }
            // Return the View
            return view;
        }

        /**
         * Destroy the item from the ViewPager. In our case this is simply
         * removing the View.
         */
        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View) object);
        }
    }
}
```

Выводит ошибку, когда я перелистываю с третьей на вторую, и даже если я просто задеваю эту вторую вкладку,

> 12-22 08:50:42.060
>   1558-1558/com.example.eldos.callreport
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main
>       Process: com.example.eldos.callreport, PID:
>   1558
>       android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error
>   inflating class fragment
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>               at com.example.eldos.callreport.fragments.ScreenOne$SamplePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(ScreenOne.java:92)
>               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:837)
>               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1021)
>               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
>               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:249)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
>   Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
>   Method)
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Binary XML file line #18: Duplicate id
>   0x7f090040, tag null, or parent id 0x0
>   with another fragment for
>   com.example.eldos.callreport.Fragment1
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2164)
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:297)
>               at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreateView(ActionBarActivity.java:547)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>               at com.example.eldos.callreport.fragments.ScreenOne$SamplePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(ScreenOne.java:92)
>               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:837)
>               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1021)
>               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
>               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:249)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
>   Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
>   Method)

Comment: Вот такая ошибка:

>aused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #18: Duplicate id 0x7f090040, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.example.eldos.callreport.Fragment1 at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас в методе `instantiateItem` выполняются 2 условия, кроме случая, когда `position = 2`.
Например, если `position = 0`, выполняется условие `if(position == 0)` и `else` из `if(position == 2)`. Используйте `switch / case`

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pager_item,container, false);
    container.addView(view);
    TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title)

    switch(position){
        case 0:
            title.setText("One");
        case 1:
            title.setText("Two");
        case 2:
            title.setText("Two+One");
        case 3:
            title.setText("Lastone");
    }

    return view;
}
```

Надеюсь, это то, о чем вы спрашиваете.

Comment: да, уже исправил, но дело не в этом, дело в том, что этот фрагмент уничтожается и потом заново создается, а заново он почему не может сформироваться, хотя там только одна кнопка и то не рабочая, или как-то можно по-другому подставлять ему страницы, кроме фрагментов.

Comment: фрагмент ScreenOne уничтожается?

Comment: Я просто смотрю код, который вы используете из github, там вроде все должно работать. Не пойму, зачем вы пытаетесь засунуть в контейнер одно и тоже.

Comment: вот здесь
 
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View) object);
        }

он уничтожается, но даже если я убираю эту строку, она все равно заново пытается создавать, вот надо бы как-то сделать, чтобы она заново не создавала, то есть могла как-то проверять есть ли такой или нету, 
или нормально пересоздавать, что более предпочтительно,

Comment: у меня вопрос, как я могу создавать вьюшки, не используя фрагменты, 
я создаю вью, направляя его на xml код, где прописан фрагмент, может, можно еще как-то по-другому более предпочтительно.

В контейнер я сую одно и то же, это только тест, позже я переделаю, когда я до конца решу эту проблему.

Comment: Вы не совсем понимаете код, который используете. Вы не работаете с объектом фрагмента напрямую, а просто в адаптере добавляете view, который будет отображаться. В методе destroyItem просто удаляются view из контейнера. Добавьте Log в методы адаптера, так будет легче понять, когда они вызываются.

Comment: да я это вижу, он удаляется и заново создается, 
но ошибка, когда он пытается создаться заново, 
он удаляет и потом заново создает еще раз при обратном возращении к нему, и пытается либо заново создать фрагмент или view.
Лучше помогите решить проблему.